# Oracle Error ORA-00922 While Compiling Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, bind-variables

I have a varchar2 datatype column in a table. User only can insert number to that column and I don't want to change as number. Sometimes while inserting data this column as manual, user can space in column. I create a trigger to avoid it. Trigger i wrote is as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF :new.column != TRIM(:new.column) THEN
     :new.column := TRIM(:new.column);
  ELSE
   dbms_output.put_line(:new.column || ' is suitable for jobid');
END IF;
END;
```

I got error like below while compiling above code.

"ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it keeps getting error. I deleted the semicolon at end of the 8th as well, but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Firstly, I only deleted for 6th but i got error. Then i also deleted for 8th, however i got error again.

Comment: Excuse me I misread, there's a problem with the syntax that TRIGGER keyword is missing after CREATE OR REPLACE , and table name which should be a reprentation I think. Since it's not possible to create a table with name table. Do you need a floating number for that column, or just digits ( integers ) ?

Comment: I forgot to write TRIGGER after CREATE OR REPLACE :)). I fixed it now. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: you're welcome.If you're insisting on not changing the data type, perhaps adding a check constraint would be a better alternative than using trigger I think. Do you need a floating number for that column, or just digits ( integers ) ?

Comment: Your trigger will not remove all spaces from the data entered; TRIM, as used, removes leading and trailing spaces. However it will not any spaces between the first and last digits. So the string '123 ' becomes '123', the string '12 3' does not, the space remains. Also how do you pervert the user from entering other non-numeric characters. If you can do that why not also disallow entey of a space. BTW your trigger can be reduced to the single line *:new.column := trim(:new.column);* to produce exactly the same result, except for the message that nobody will ever see, beyond development.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ORA-00922` is caused by the missing keyword `TRIGGER`, as pointed out by [Barbaros Özhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841306). Just add it, assuming you got the table name and column name correct, then it would do fine.

---

But going further your inquiry, it seems you wanted to replace all the spaces entered by the user for that column. If so, this trigger could do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.column_name != REPLACE(:new.column_name,' ','') THEN
    :new.column_name := REPLACE(:new.column_name,' ','');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.column_name|| ' is suitable for jobid');
  END IF;
END;
```

I added the missing keyword `trigger`.
Just replace the `table_name` and `column_name` to their correct names and it should work.